# Flex PNGEncoder lose transparent quality

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I've got problem with transparent using PNGEncoder class. When I encode BitmapData to png and use it as source of my Image, it looks terrible. I attach example. There are two images - first colorful and above him white with alpha gradient.

[Image before save](http://postimage.org/image/6ac2xqxop/)

[Image after save](http://postimage.org/image/ptgo73wg9/)

I've used some other libraries like AsPngEncoder, but it didn't help. It's code I use:

```
        var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(container.width, container.height, true, 0xffffff);
        bd.draw(container);
        var pngenc:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();

        var pngByteArray:ByteArray = pngenc.encode(bd);

        container.source = pngByteArray;
        var fl:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("./images/file.png");

        var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
        fs.open(fl, FileMode.WRITE);
        fs.writeBytes(pngByteArray);
        fs.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use new Flash Player 11.3 feature

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS4768145595f94108-17913eb4136eaab51c7-8000.html

Comment: It doesn't help. All is the same.